# WidgetKit customize Intent parameters selection

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit

I'm building a widget for an app in iOS with WidgetKit, SwiftUI etc.
I've created a custom intent and custom object to use in the app and when tapping on `"Edit Widget"` I take a custom list of items from `UserDefaults`.

The question is, can I customize the appearance of the second view that iOS shows me with the list of items etc?

This is the view I'm talking about:

[image]

Looking around I found this: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10194
that gives me a lot of good hints but nothing on what i'm trying to achieve.

In the video they show this:

[image]

That seams to be the same view but with some customization.

My end goal is to remove the search bar.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create items for the `INObjectCollection` for your `Intent` you can set:

- `identifier`
- `display`
- `pronunciationHint`
- `subtitle`
- `image`

Here is an example how to add `subtitle` and `image` to the `INObjectCollection` item:

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, TestIntentHandling {
    func provideItemsOptionsCollection(for intent: TestIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Item>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let items: [Item] = [
            .init(
                identifier: "1",
                display: "SoupPay Credit",
                subtitle: "$248.20",
                image: nil
            ),
            .init(
                identifier: "2",
                display: "SoupPay Titanium Credit",
                subtitle: "$602.01",
                image: nil
            ),
            .init(
                identifier: "3",
                display: "Apple Card",
                subtitle: "$17.28",
                image: nil
            ),
            .init(
                identifier: "4",
                display: "Other Card",
                subtitle: "$123.32",
                image: INImage(url: URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/200px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png")!)!
            ),
        ]
        completion(INObjectCollection(items: items), nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Totally missed that.
Do you know how to customize color too?

Comment: @MajinDageta I didn't try it but I assume you need to set the `accentColor` of the Widget (can be changed in the `Assets.xcassets`).